# how to select first not null field in each group when group by in dot net entity code first

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-code-first, code-first, webapi

I have a Model with a `field` type of `string`.

I want to make a query in `group by` get `first` item of each `group`.

but with this condition that first item `string field` is `not null`

i run this query in my code but got error

```
var items = appDbContext.Foods.GroupBy(r => r.Category)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key,image= g.Where(r=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Image)).First().Image??"" })
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.image);
```

I got below error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: f.Category, 
ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: Foods
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False

    .Where(r => !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Image)))
    .Select(s => s.Image)
    .First()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

My `C#` model :

```
    public class Foods
    {
        public int FoodId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset InsertDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the model class with all the properties

Comment: The code quoted in the error is not the same as the code you provided. Can you double check if that error was generated by that code?

Comment: @DragosStoica add my model

Comment: @CristianTeodorov i check it . its correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to hide the categories without images, you could do it like this:

```
foods.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Image))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

Basically, you can filter out all the items without images and then use the group by. However, if a category(group) has all the items without images, it will be skipped.

If you want to have the null categories also, this works for me (note that this was tested with in-memory collections, not with EF)

```
var foods = new List<Foods>()
{
    new Foods()
    {
        FoodId = 1,
        Name = "Test1",
        Price = 20,
        Image = "my-image",
        Category = "category1",
        Description = "description1",
        InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
        IsActive = true
    },
    new Foods()
    {
        FoodId = 1,
        Name = "Test2",
        Price = 20,
        Image = "my-image",
        Category = "category1",
        Description = "description1",
        InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
        IsActive = true
    },
    new Foods()
    {
        FoodId = 1,
        Name = "Test3",
        Price = 20,
        Category = "category2",
        Description = "description1",
        InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
        IsActive = true
    },
    new Foods()
    {
        FoodId = 1,
        Name = "Test4",
        Price = 20,
        Category = "category2",
        Description = "description1",
        InsertDate = DateTimeOffset.Now,
        IsActive = true
    }
};

var filteredFoods = foods
    .GroupBy(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault( t=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Image)) ?? x.First());
```

Comment: its right . but i want all category .even without image.

Comment: added example with in-memory collections, hope it helps

Comment: FirstOrDefault(t => !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Image))) could not be translated

Comment: yeah, what ORM are you using? probably it's not able to translate this query in SQL

Comment: Entity FrameWork Core

Comment: then I think you should use sub-queries like this:
        var items = appDbContext.Foods.GroupBy(r => r.Category)
            .Select(g => new { g.Key, image = appDbContext.Foods.Where(r => r.Category ==g.Key && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Image)).FirstOrDefault() ?? "" })
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.image);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244654/discussion-between-dragos-stoica-and-mhsankar).